# Hook strcmp using LD_PRELOAD in linux?

Tags: c, dynamic, hook

As i want to hook strcmp, Code is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    printf("hooked strcmp\n");
    return 0;
}

// gcc test.c -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    strcmp(argv[1], "aba");         // didn't call strcmp in libtest
    int i = strcmp(argv[1], "aba"); // call strcmp in libtest
}

// gcc main.c
// LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./a.out 12123
```

My Question is : Why strcmp diffs in this two conditions ?

Comment: Intrinsic is in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the value returned by `strcmp`, then the call does nothing. So the compiler is free to remove the call. Under some circumstances, the compiler might also inline the call to `strcmp`, since it knows precisely what `strcmp` does.

This is condoned by the standard, which reserves all identifiers declared in standard library headers (whether or not the header is actually included):

§7.1.3/1: "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses [i.e. standard library headers]… are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.

§7.1.3/2: "If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4)… the behavior is undefined.

The exception, as per §7.1.4/2: "Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header."

---

Since defining your own `strcmp` is clearly undefined behaviour (unless you use a standalone compiler), it should probably simply be avoided. However, in practice it may be possible to do in a non-portable way with some common compilers.

First, you must avoid including the `string.h` standard library header. The standard C library headers distributed with gcc declare `strcmp` with [`__attribute__((pure))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute):

> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables.  Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be.  These functions should be declared with the attribute `pure`.

This declaration (which is an extension to the C standard) lets the compiler eliminate the first call to `strcmp` because it believes that the function has no side-effects (which would include writing to stdout). Both gcc and clang will eliminate the first call even without optimization.

You can convince clang to compile both calls to `strcmp`, you can avoid the elimination simply by not including the `string.h` header (and declaring `strcmp` yourself without the `pure` attribute). But that's not sufficient with gcc because gcc, by default, automatically includes declarations of inline versions of many standard library functions (the current list can be found [here in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins).) As mentioned by that last link, you can suppress the automatic declaration by adding `-fno-builtin-strcmp` to the command line (as well as not including the standard header).

Comment: thanks! It works, as i removed #include <string.h> and compile with -fno-builtin-strcmp.